# Validation that checks if any nested attributes contain a value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, nested-attributes

I'm trying to write a validation that checks if one of the nested attributes that belong to a model contains a certain value.

In this case I have a Questions model that contains many Answers.  I need a validation that checks to see if at least one of the questions has a correct answer marked.

This is an app for creating tests.  The question has several answers but not all of them are the correct one.

Here's my Question model:

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :examination
    has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :responses

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, allow_destroy: true, :reject_if => :all_blank

    validates_presence_of :body
    validates_presence_of :question_type

    validate :has_correct_ans?

     private

     def has_correct_ans?
      errors.add(:correct, "You must select at least one correct answer") unless
      self.answers.exists?(correct: true)
     end
end
```

Here's the Answer model

```
class Answer < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :question
    has_many :responses, dependent: :destroy

end
```

I attempted to write a method called "has_correct_ans?" to check if any of the answers contain the correct attribute.  This fails every time though.  I assume that's because prior to saving the data doesn't exist in the database.  From testing in the console that command works fine on existing data.
i.e. `Question.find.answers.exists?(correct: true)`

will return true for questions in which one of the answers has the correct attribute.

Id really like this to work as a validation.  I just don't know how to access the nested attribute prior to save.

This is what the params look like:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"dOf8H1Wqark3TZAGgX6kaY5Yt4kYKm1FNbCnNi4BlVTTQV9PijlkA1bNS8Qi8DwLLxV6FkWzNbmiT6X+7Vr6Xg==", "question"=>{"body"=>"gfdgdfs", "question_type"=>"Multiple Choice", "points"=>"1", "answers_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"correct"=>"true", "body"=>"dggf", "_destroy"=>"0"}}}, "commit"=>"Submit", "examination_id"=>"12"}
```

I also tried to do this in the controller using the params.  Here's what my create function looks like:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @exam = Examination.find(params[:examination_id])
    @question = @exam.questions.build(question_params)
    ans_params = params[:question][:answers_attributes]
    @correct_ans = false
    ans_params.each do |k, v|
      if @correct_ans == false
       @correct_ans =  v.has_key?(:correct)
      end
    end

    if @exam.questions.count > 0
      @question.position = @exam.questions.count + 1 
    else 
      @question.position = 1
    end
    if @correct_ans == true && @question.save
      redirect_to @exam, notice: "question created successfully"
    elsif @question.save
      flash[:error] = "You need a correct answer"
      render :new
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

That doesn't actually work either.  It still saves even though there is no correct answer.  I don't want to do it in the controller anyway.  It would work much better as a validation.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here.  Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Sorry, can't check it right now in console. Maybe `errors.add(...) if answers.where(correct: true).size == 0`?

Comment: That has the same effect as what I had in the method already.  Just tried it.

Comment: Try this:   `errors.add(...) if answers.map{ |x| x[:correct] ==  true }.size == 0?`  You can not use where query here since it fires database call and no records present. You could use any other method to get the data without making call to database since it is not inserted to DB (validation Phase). Here I have used map to achieve the same. You can use any other method as your wish !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

Thanks, Ashik.  I had no idea that you can use methods like that, even though the data is not in the database.

I tried your idea.  It didn't return the right result but was really close.

answers.map{ |x| x[:correct] == true }.size == 0?

Returns an array of the correct attributes for all the Answers records.  Like this:

```
[false, false, true]
```

I changed the method a little bit to this:

```
answers.map{ |x| x[:correct]}.include? true
```

Which returns true if any of the records contain a correct.  I tried it in my validation method and it works perfectly.

Here's the updated Question model.

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :examination
    has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :responses

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, allow_destroy: true, :reject_if => :all_blank

    validates_presence_of :body
    validates_presence_of :question_type

    validate :has_correct_ans?

     private

     def has_correct_ans?
      errors.add(:correct, "You must select at least one correct answer") unless
      answers.map{ |x| x[:correct]}.include? true

     end
end
```